# django session value different then originally set

Tags: django, session

First off I have `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in my settings

Using OAuth 2.0, I have a view that sends the user to login the QuickBooks

```
def get_CSRF_token(request):
    token = request.session.get('csrfToken', None)
    if token is None:
        token = getSecretKey()
        request.session['csrfToken'] = token
    return token

def connectToQuickbooks(request):
    url = getDiscoveryDocument.auth_endpoint
    params = {
        'scope': settings.ACCOUNTING_SCOPE,
        'redirect_uri': settings.REDIRECT_URI,
        'response_type': 'code',
        'state': get_CSRF_token(request),
        'client_id': settings.CLIENT_ID
    }
    url += '?' + urlencode(params)
    return redirect(url)
```

getSecretKey generates some random 40 character string

Then QuickBooks sends back the same random string I saved into the session in the `state` parameter

```
def authCodeHandler(request):
    state = request.GET.get('state', None)
    error = request.GET.get('error', None)
    csrfToken = get_CSRF_token(request)
    print("State: " + state + " csrfToken: " + csrfToken)
    if error == 'access_denied':
        return redirect('index')
    if state is None:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    elif state != csrfToken:  # validate against CSRF attacks
        return HttpResponse('unauthorized', status=401)
...
...
```

But when get_CSRF_token is called it gives me something different than I put in the session.